# Exchange 2013 restring emails sent per day

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

In Exchange 2013 is there a way to restrict the amount of emails sent per day? I want to make sure nobody is sending spam mail to 1000s of recipients at the time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have to answer my own question.

Create a throttling policy and set RecipientRateLimit or MessageRateLimit. One does per 24 hours and the other does like per minute.